# Compose apply-style functions in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In scala, functions can be composed

```
def f = { x:Int => x + 420}
f.compose(f)
```

there's also a way to define function application for an object

```
object F {
  var y = 420
  def apply (x: Int) = x + y
}
println(F(3))
```

how do I compose these function-like objects? The following doesn't work.

```
println(F.compose(F))
```

Comment: Does it have to be an object? How about `val f = new Function[Int, Int] { ... }`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz that's basically what I defined in my first code snippet, I was just curious if there was a way to compose objects which have `apply` defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create an anonymous function `F(_)` and compose those: `F(_).compose(F(_))` (EDIT: see Victor Moroz's comment).
2. You can also make your object a function: `object F extends (Int => Int)` and write `F.compose(F)`.

Comment: 1. `(F(_)).compose(F(_: Int))` or `(F(_)).compose[Int](F(_))`

Comment: Weird: I understand why the parentheses around first `F(_)` are needed (it's `x => F(x).compose(F(_))` without them) but not why the compiler can't infer the type argument.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to accomplish this:

```
F.apply _ compose F.apply _
```